# Is there a way to add a specific version of a file to the git index?

Tags: git

The reason I am asking this is that I had accidentally done a `git commit -a` that included a file I did not yet want to commit. My solution was to do the following:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
git reset -- file/with/changes_not_to_committed
git commit -C HEAD@{1}
```

Here, I’ve rewound the branch by one commit while keeping the index and working tree, then pulled `file/with/changes_not_to_committed` from a yet older revision into the index, and then I committed the index using the commit message from the previous branch head commit. Neither `git-reset` invocation touches the working copy, so my modifications to `file/with/changes_not_to_committed` persist, but are no longer recorded in the `HEAD` revision.

However, it would have been easier if I could pull `file/with/changes_not_to_committed` from the `HEAD^` revision right into the index *without touching the working copy*. Since the index otherwise already represents the state I want, I could then just amend the `HEAD` commit, producing a sequence like this:

```
git magic-pony HEAD^ file/with/changes_not_to_committed
git commit --amend -C HEAD
```

This is *almost* what I would get by replacing `git-magic-pony` with `git-checkout`, except for the requirement that the working copy be left untouched and only the index updated. It seems there is no way to make `git-checkout` not touch both.

My question is: does `git-magic-pony` exist, and if so, under what name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right.  When you want to move revisions from HEAD or another revision to the index, you use 'git reset REVISION -- file' - then, you'd use 'git commit --amend' to revise the commit.  As it happens I'm currently working on a review aimed towards making it more obvious how files can be moved from A to B like that.

Of course a much easier way is to crank up 'git-gui', click the 'amend last commit' button, then click on the icon by the file in the commit inventory section of the gui, and then 'commit'.

Comment: Thanks! That’s exactly what I was looking for. I disagree about the GUI being easier, though. :-)  More discoverable, perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you can do something like this using [`git update-index`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git-core/docs/git-update-index.html):

```
git update-index --cacheinfo 100644 5be7e154c284fb8de8ddca0bb18b72a73089df9b filename
```

You will need to get the mode (100644 above) and sha1 of the file you want to go back to (you can get this info all from [`git ls-tree`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-tree.html)). Then you can `git commit --amend` and your working copy will not be affected.

Answer (score 2):

<del>So based on Greg Hewgill’s answer, `git-magic-pony` is a shell script I would write which looks like this:</del>

```
#!/bin/sh
git ls-tree "$@" | while read mode type hash path ; do
    git update-index --cacheinfo $mode $hash "$path"
done
```